# Can not upload image to NodeJs server using Multer

Tags: node.js, image, multer

I am trying to upload image to to server and store it in a separate folder. I am submitting multipart form with image attached to it but I am not getting any errors, response is always successfull even when I am trying to submit an empty form. Is there are any suggestions why it is not working?

**controller.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const shortid = require('shortid');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({ 
    destination: function (req, file, cb) { 
        cb(null, "/home/username/projects/data/img/"); // Static route to save images
        console.log("DESTINATION CB: " + cb);
    }, 
    filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
        cb(null, shortid.generate() +".jpg");
    } 
});
       
const maxSize = 10 * 1000 * 1000; // 10 MB Max Picture size
    
var upload = multer({  
    storage: storage, 
    limits: { fileSize: maxSize }, 
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb){ 
        // Set the filetypes, it is optional 
        var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/; 
        var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype); 

        var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()); 

        if (mimetype && extname) { 
            return cb(null, true); 
        }
      
        cb("Error: File upload only supports the " + "following filetypes - " + filetypes); 
      }  
}).single('image');

module.exports = {
    createBlog: function(req, res, next) {
        upload(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                res.json({status: "Error", error_message: "Some kind of error with image"});
            } else {
                res.json({status: "Success", success_message: "Image uploaded successfully."});
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**route.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../app/api/controllers/controller');

router.post('/blog/create', controller.createBlog)

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const logger = require('morgan');

const route = require('./routes/route');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('./config/database'); // DB configuration
const app = express();

// Connection to mongodb
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));

app.use('/blogx', route);

app.get('/favicon.ico', function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(204);
});

// Handle 404 error
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        let err = new Error('Not Found!');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
});

// Handle errors
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.status === 404) {
                res.status(404).json({message: "Not Found!"});
        } else {
                res.status(500).json({message: "Something looks wrong :("});
        }
});

app.listen(3001, function(){ 
    console.log('MAIN Server is listening on port 3001');
});
```

And this is how I am trying to submit form using Insomnia
[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggohc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make sure that the upload directory `/home/username/projects/data/img/` exists before starting the server/executing the request.

Note that you would have been able to detect this kind of error yourself, if your error logic also had handled non-multer errors, as in this case instead of a multer error a [system error](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) (NOENT) is thrown :

```
upload(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                res.json({status: "Error", error_message: "Some kind of error with multer"});
            } else if(err) {
                res.json({status: "Error", error_message: err.message});
            } else {
                res.json({status: "Success", success_message: "Image uploaded successfully."});
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just changed error handling and it is still sending as a success response. Directory exists as I was able to download images that was pre uploaded manually. For some reasons functions inside of storage and upload variables never been called if I would put console.log() in there. Not sure what could be the problem

Comment: Hm ok, that's weird. Can you export your request as a `curl` from insomnia and post it here? I've tested your code locally on my machine successfully with the following request : `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/blogx/blog/create' \
--form 'image=@"/path/to/image.jpeg"'`

Comment: This is my request
`curl --location --request POST 'http://192.168.0.2:3001/blogx/blog/create' \ --form 'image=@"/C:/Users/Home/Desktop/blogx_logo.png"'`
I was trying to submit this request even without `image` field and it still giving me the same response

Comment: Just to be sure - can you `console.log(req.file)` inside the `upload` callback?

Comment: Oh here you go, I wasn't able to see because of my console color scheme, it returns `undefined` for `console.log(req.file)`